# Rails 3 - extra item with each method for nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Quick question, why would there be an extra item output with an each method in Rails?

For example:

```
<% @consultation.messages.each do |message| %>
   <div class="message">
      <%= message.subject %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

This puts out an extra message div at the bottom of the screen for some reason. I've checked the database, there is no extra message on that thread.

Is this to do with the fact that it's a nested resource?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

---

Controller code is:

```
def show
  @consultation = Consultation.find(params[:id])
end
```

Note: I have changed the controller name since posting (everything else has been changed to this new name (model etc))

Comment: if you do <%=message.id%> what do you see?

Comment: Nothing for that extra result. It only seems to output the HTML, there's no id. I've got a suspicion it's to do with the fact it's nested.

Comment: Even if message were nil for the last item, nil.id returns 4 in development and throws an error in production. What HTML comes after that loop?

Comment: Perhaps you're doing something like @thread.messages.build in your controller? Can you post the controller code?

Comment: What does `Thread.find(your_id).messages.inspect` give you in irb?

Comment: @netmute if I use the rails console I just 2 messages, there are 3 div's outputted with only 2 populated.

Comment: @tybro0103 There's no HTML after that each loop in the view, just a partial for footer then closing of the body and html elements. Controller code is above...

Comment: Consider to remove the question as its not helpful for community.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be caused by using a .build within a form that comes before my each loop.